# extracting keys from json string using json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

can someone tell me how to extract keys from json using json4s.
My use case:
json stored as string in scala variable:

```
 {
 "key1" : "val1",
 "key2" : ["12", "32"],
 "key3" : {"keyN" : "valN"}
 }
```

I'd like to transform this into a following Map[String, String]:

```
 (key1 -> "val1", key2 -> "[\"12\",\"32\"]", key3 -> "{\"keyN\":\"valN\"}"
```

is there a simple way to achieve this with json4s? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val result: Map[String, String] = parse( """ {
                                           | "key1" : "val1",
                                           | "key2" : ["12", "32"],
                                           | "key3" : {"keyN" : "valN"}
                                           | }""".stripMargin).mapField(k => {
  val v: String = k._2 match {
    case s: JString => k._2.extract[String]
    case _ => write(k._2)
  }
  (k._1, JString(v))
}).extract[Map[String, String]]
println(result)
```

You can use `mapField` map the `JValue` toString

- if the value's type is `String` just extract as String
- if the value's type is others, use the `json4s` to parse it to as `JSON` string
- finally extract the `JValue` as  `Map[String, String]`.

Comment: thanks, works fine. I didn't see mapField method which is a key here :(

Answer (score 0):

```scala
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val a = parse(""" { "numbers" : [1, 2, 3, 4] } """)
println(a.extract[Map[String, Any]].keySet)
```